# change color of a text in php with echo

Tags: php, text, colors, echo, sam

I use Sambroadcaster

change color of a text in php with echo

this is the code:

```
<span id="currently-playing-title"><?php echo $currentSong->artist_title;; ?></span><?php if ($currentSong->isRequested) echo "[Request]"; ?>
```

This is the text that i want to change the color **[Request]**

The next code is:

```
<?php if($comingSong->isRequested): ?>[Request]
```

In this line i want also change the color of the text **[Request]**

In the css there is no rule al the text colors are white

Any idea?

I try to find a solution in the css file but there is no rule herfore

Answer (score 0):

How about writing out some escape sequences?

```
echo "\033[01;31m [Request] \033[0m"";
```

this line only work in console

Another way is writing out some HTML tags and some CSS if you're outputting this to the browser?

```
echo '<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;"> [Request] </span>';
```

Remember last line  code Won't work from console though, only through browser.

Comment: Yess the last one works great,!

Comment: Vote up the answer please

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hammad this one works great!
Thanks!!!